# How to verify logger.error(String message, Throwable t) in Junit testcase using Mockito

Tags: java, spring-boot, junit, mockito

I am trying to test Kafka callback onFailure method:

```
     @Override
        public void onFailure(Throwable ex) {
        logger.error("Failure while sending message in kafka.", ex);
            }

My test case code using Mockito. I am setting exception in object of class SettableListenableFuture.



   SettableListenableFuture<SendResult<String, DeserializationResult<EnvelopeExpanded<SpecificRecord>>>> future2 = new SettableListenableFuture<>();
                future2.setException(new Exception("Could not publish to Kafka"));
    Exception ex = new Exception("Could not publish to Kafka");
    verify(logger, times(1)).error("Failure while sending message in kafka.", ex);
```

I am getting this error

```
  Argument(s) are different! Wanted:
    logger.error(
        "Failure while sending message in kafka.",
        java.lang.Exception: Could not publish to Kafka
    );

    Actual invocation has different arguments:
    logger.error(
        "Failure while sending message in kafka.",
        java.lang.Exception: Could not publish to Kafka
    );
```

Both wanted and actual arguments are same but it still throws error. Can anyone help me with this ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`System.out.println(new Exception("Could not publish to Kafka").equals(new Exception("Could not publish to Kafka")))` will print `false`

so

```
   Exception ex = new Exception("Could not publish to Kafka");
   SettableListenableFuture<...> future2 = new SettableListenableFuture<>();
            future2.setException(ex);
   verify(logger, times(1)).error("Failure while sending message in kafka.", ex);
```

should work